# Bijective proof of recurrence for rooted unlabeled trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, trees, bijective-combinatorics

Would've been a better question for Christmas than Thanksgiving, but alas...

Let $t_n$ denote the number of rooted, unlabeled trees on $n$ vertices ([OEIS A000081](http://oeis.org/A000081)). These are the isomorphism classes of rooted trees under root-preserving isomorphisms. Let $T(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1} t_n z^n$ be the corresponding generating function. In 1937, using his [enumeration under symmetry theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem), Pólya showed that
$$ T(z) = z \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{T(z^i)}{i}}.$$
By differentiating this identity one obtains the recurrence
$$ (n-1)\cdot t_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}t_{n-i}\sum_{m \mid i}mt_{m}$$
for $n> 1$. This is such a nice recurrence that I wonder:

**Question**: Is there a bijective proof of this recurrence for $t_n$?

Comment: I'd really want $\left(n-1\right) \cdot t_n$ to be something like the number of unlabeled rooted trees with one chosen non-root vertex $v$. In that case, we could split up such a tree into the child-tree of the root that contains $v$, along with all other child-trees of the roots that are isomorphic to it, and the tree that remains (including the root). That should give the right hand side (the $t_m$ counts the possibilities for the former child-tree; the $m$ the options for the location of $v$ in it; the $t_{n-i}$ counts the remaining trees). Unfortunately, it isn't, because automorphisms ...

Comment: ... of the tree can move $v$ around. But there should be a way to deal with this, as I suspect it's a common issue with unlabeled objects and looks solvable. I suspect that, rather than counting unlabeled trees, we should really count labeled trees modulo some group actions.

Comment: Wait, what exactly is an unlabeled tree? Are the children of a node a list or a multiset?

Comment: Two rooted unlabeled trees are considered the same if there is an isomorphism between them which maps the root to the root.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought right away (was merely confused by the different use in algebraic combinatorics, where "labeled" is an extra layer of labels). If so, I'm thinking we could use another way to remove the "up to isomorphism" part: We pin each unlabeled tree to a given form by arranging all children of each node in increasing order (according to some arbitrary but fixed order on trees). Let me call a rooted tree in which the children of each node are arranged in increasing order from left to right a *well-increasing tree* (stupid name, but sufficiently novel to avoid confusion). Now, ...

Comment: ... it is indeed true that $\left(n-1\right) \cdot t_n$ counts the well-increasing trees with one chosen non-root vertex $v$. My argument sketched above should thus work, or do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Oh. My bijection is not a bijection, since the "remaining tree" could already have a copy of the $v$-containing child-tree as a child-tree. Let me see if this can be fixed.

Comment: In particular where is the $m\mid i$ condition coming from?

Comment: The $m \mid i$ condition is because the joint size of several copies of an $m$-vertex tree is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused by your initial idea: mustn't $v$ be the root of a sub-tree that contains $m$ vertices? So, in what sense are there "$m$ options for the location of $v$ in this sub-tree"?

Comment: Oh, I see. Instead of removing the $v$-containing child-tree and all child-trees isomorphic to it, we remove the $v$-containing child-tree and all child-trees *to its left* that are isomorphic to it. The ones to its right remain. Thus, when reinserting these removed child-trees, we don't have to wonder which of them $v$ will be lying in, only where on that tree it will lie. That should finally work.

Comment: I'm talking only of child-trees -- i.e., subtrees rooted at the (direct) children of the root. If you are defining trees recursively lists of lists of lists ..., then the child-trees of a tree $\left(t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_k\right)$ are $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_k$.

Comment: No, $v$ is the chosen non-root vertex in the big tree. Should we zoom? This is a tricky proof to write up well and I have less time than usual.

Comment: Re-reading your comments I now get the idea, Darij. I will accept your answer when you post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Late edit**: having now read through the OP comments, I can see that my proof is essentially a carbon copy of @darij.grinberg's approach (although my derivation was independent). I'm okay to delete this answer once/if darij chooses to post theirs.

Pick a canonical ordering of unlabelled rooted trees, say, with lexicographical comparison of tuples $(n, T_1, \ldots, T_k)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices, $T_1, \ldots, T_k$ is the non-descending sequence of children subtrees. Throughout $T, T_1, T_2$ are unlabelled rooted trees in canonical form (that is, subtrees of any vertex are ordered as above).

Let $A_n$ be the set of pairs $(T, v)$ with $|T| = n$, $v$ is a non-root vertex of $T$. Also, let $B_n$ be the set of tuples $(T_1, T_2, k, u)$ such that $|T_1| + k|T_2| = n$, $u$ is a vertex of $T_2$. Observe that $|A_n|$ and $|B_n|$ are LHS and RHS of the recurrence in OP, more readily seen by rewriting $(n - 1)t_n = \sum_{m = 1}^{n - 1}mt_m \sum_{0 < km < n} t_{n - km}$.

The bijection between $A_n$ and $B_n$ is as follows:

- we associate $(T_1, T_2, k, u)$ to $(T, v)$ by:

  - $T_2$ = the subtree of $T$ containing $v$,
  - $u$ = the respective vertex of $T_2$,
  - $k$ = the number of children subtrees of $T$ isomorphic to $T_2$ not later than the copy containing $v$ in the ordered sequence of children subtrees,
  - $T_1$ = the result of removing the $k$ children subtrees from $T$.
- we associate $(T, v)$ to $(T_1, T_2, k, u)$ by inserting $k$ copies of $T_2$ as children subtrees of the root of $T_1$ (and naming the result $T$), and picking the respective vertex $u$ in the $k$-th copy as $v$.

Comment: Sorry if there was a sufficient resolution in the comments already, it was a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is exactly what Darij explained.

Comment: Yep, that looks like my proof, explained sequentially rather than as a mess of comments :) I was trying to do it myself, but getting confused about the notion of a vertex. OTOH, I think your equality $(n - 1)t_n = \sum_{m = 1}^{n - 1}mt_m \sum_{0 < km < n} t_{n - km}$ is slightly buggy (some $m$s should be $n-m$s, right?).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't think so? Here $km$ functions as $i$ in the OP formula. The actual inner summation is by $k$ via notation abuse.

Comment: Oh, I see! Sorry.

Comment: Had similar (although more general) question, didn't find this question, had to reinvent the same idea myself: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494715/euler-transform-without-generating-functions